# How to transform true and false to 1 and 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following code:

```
  var newValue = ($(event.target).is(":checked")) ? 1 : 0;
  var oldValue = (!$(event.target).is(":checked")) ? 1 : 0;
  sendMessage(this.name, oldValue, newValue);
```

Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sendMessage(this.name, +!event.target.checked, +event.target.checked)`

Not your sending `sendMessage(text, !bool, bool)` which is silly just send one bool.

Also `$(thing).is(":checked")` is stupid (jQuery ಠ_ಠ)

Comment: LA_, note that `+true == 1`, and `+false == 0` in JS.

Comment: The real answer is in the comments

Answer (score 6):

As Cygal noted in one of the comments, using the [`unary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29) operator (+) coerces `true` and `false` into numbers. So doing `+true` will yield 1 while using `+false` will yield 0.

Comment: The `+` is not "the" unary operator, it's **one example of** a unary operator. It's called "unary" because it takes one argument. Even the page you linked references another unary operator (-). You can compare with ternary operators—which take three arguments (e.g. foo ? bar : bat)—and many binary operators (e.g. foo + bar). The bang (!) is also a common unary operator.

Answer (score 3):

For the record: `Number` will also convert to 1 or 0:

```
sendMessage(this.name, Number(!event.target.checked), Number(event.target.checked));
```

Answer (score 3):

Ah I forgot that rep doesn't transfer over, apparently I don't have enough to comment. I was going to reply to Cygal's comment on Raynos's answer:

While it is true that `+true == 1`, and `+false == 0` that isn't exactly helpful since `true == 1` and `false == 0` as well. You probably meant to say that  `+true === 1` and `+false === 0`